# How do I Enable ScrollViewer in RibbonMenuButton like in Header menu of MSWord 2007

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon

I'm using Ribbon Control for Our UI. For one Feature we have to show no.of Values via `RibbonMenuItem` of `RibbonMenuButton`.

Now issue is , Values are huge, so the UI looks drop bottom of the screen. I need to control via `ScrollViewer` like What MSWord 2007 Header menu button looks like.

Expected UI: [image]

Current our UI: [image]

I'm trying to enable

```
<Custom:RibbonMenuButton ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                         MaxHeight="300" 
                         >
```

But no luck

Comment: What XML markup did you use for the custom UI? Could you be more specific?

Comment: Thanks for reply @EugeneAstafiev...   
i'm using Microsoft ribbon controller [msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff799534(v=vs.110).aspx]

Comment: Try the same thing, but on the [RibbonGallery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbongallery.aspx)